# How to access the 'comment' method inside a helper class in codeception

Tags: codeception

Is it possible to access the `comment()` method inside the acceptance class?

I have a helper method in **Acceptance.php** in which I'm trying to use the `comment()` method but it always returns as "undefined", I tried these to no avail

```
        $this->getModule('WebDriver')->comment('hai');
        $I->comment('hai!');
        $this->comment('hai!');
        $obj = $this->getModule('Asserts');
        $obj->comment('hai');
        $webDriver->comment('hai');
        $webDriver->browser->comment('hai');
        $this->browser->comment('hai');
        $webDriver->_comment('hai');
```

How does one do it?

I could pass the $I as an argument to the method, but is there not a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I'm using the `debug()` method, which performs a similar function, but maybe someone has a different solution.